# Convert Apache Camel JSON data format from XML to Java DSL

Tags: java, json, jackson, apache-camel, integration

We're converting legacy Camel routes from XML to Java DSL, having trouble with JSON/Jackson data format we use for marshalling. This is how we do it in XML:

```
<camelContext id="camelContext">
    <dataFormats>
        <json id="json"
            library="Jackson"
            allowJmsType="true"
            disableFeatures="WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS"/>
    </dataFormats>
</camel>

 <route id="myRoute">
    <from uri="seda:inqueue"/>
      <marshal>
          <json library="Jackson" />
      </marshal>
      <to  uri="seda:outqueue />
  </route>
```

...and this is the Java version (so far)...

```
@Bean(name = "json")
    public JacksonDataFormat jacksonDataFormat() {
        JacksonDataFormat format = new JacksonDataFormat();
        format.setAllowJmsType(true);
        format.disableFeature(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
        return format;
}

from("seda:inqueue")
    .marshal(json)
    .to("seda:outqueue");
```

Am I on the right path?

Also, what is the difference between these two methods? My guess is the first one converts Json TEXT to byte stream, the second converts an object to Json TEXT; is that accurate?

```
from("seda:inqueue")
    .marshal(json)
    .to("seda:outqueue");

from("seda:inqueue")
    .json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
    .to("seda:outqueue");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use Camel XML Json component to achieve this rather than blindly migrating them. [XML JSON component](https://camel.apache.org/xmljson.html)

.marshal can used for generating any format based on configurations like BeanIO streams, CSV records and so on..json can be used for generating the JSON only.

Comment: Not sure how that helps, the legacy Camel code from which we're migrating doesn't use XML; it's all POJO's and JSON.